# Light or lights in a sentence

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Both the earth and the moon do not shine by their own **light**.
>
> Both the earth and the moon do not shine by their own **lights**.

I can't decide whether the word light is "countable or uncountable" in this sentence.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+shine+by+their+own+light%2C+shine+by+their+own+lights&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshine%20by%20their%20own%20light%3B%2Cc0), it's almost always singular *light*. Some of those instances might be "singular they", but the fact of the matter is plural ***lights*** doesn't occur often enough to even chart. I don't think this is a *countable/uncountable noun* issue though.

Answer (score 1):

The singular

> light

is appropriate since

> Both the earth and moon do not have their own source of **light**.

also

> The earth has many **lights** from cities, but does not have its own **light**.

In your example, **own** refers to **earth** and **moon** and if illuminated would have one source of **light**.